# Direct3D (DirectX) web browser Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, directx

I am developing a Direct3D application on Windows phone 8 and would like to add a web browser to display html and optionally run simple JavaScript.

The only answers online are old (2008) and seem outdated since they speak about Win32.

Is there a way to display a web browser in a pure Direct3D application ?
Any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks!